# How to reference the default style ControlTemplate for ListViewItem in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, controltemplate

In WPF, if I apply a `GridView` to a `ListView`, then it will automatically change the `Template` property of the `ListViewItem` to a `ControlTemplate` that uses a `GridViewRowPresenter` instead of a `ContentPresenter`.  This is usually what you want.

As it happens, though, I have a case where I want to keep the original `ContentPresenter`, so that it will render the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListView`.

(For the curious: I'm doing a parent-child thing where the columns are actually for the child elements, so while I do still have a `GridViewRowPresenter`, it's inside another list control inside the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListView`.)

I *can* do this by setting an `ItemContainerStyle` on the `ListView`, and setting the `Template` property in that to a custom `ControlTemplate`, since this will override the style setter that the `GridView` applies.

However this gets really wordy (especially to keep the selection colours) and it breaks the natural theme support, unless I make duplicate copies of the template for each theme, which is definitely silly.

What I really want to do is to write this:

```
<Setter Property="Template"
        Value="{StaticResource {FindDefaultControlTemplate ListViewItem}}" />
```

Where the latter bypasses the `ControlTemplate` set by the `GridView` and obtains the `ControlTemplate` that a normal `ListViewItem` would have used.

Alternatively, if there's some way to tell a `GridView` to not alter the `ListViewItem` style at all, that would also work for my scenario.

This has to work inside XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the magic incantation is to set this style:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}" />
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Apparently `ListViewItem` itself doesn't have a default style, but `ListBoxItem` does.

And this does override whatever `GridView` does and makes it use a plain `ContentPresenter` again.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this important note, which I missed on other places and causes confusion to developers: `ListViewItem` --> default style is `ListBoxItem`